# Event sales_order_save_commit_after doesn't get triggered when I create shipment for specific order progrmatically

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, module

I have created a custom extension which contains event sales_order_shipment_save_after. It's get triggered when I create shipment for order from admin panel of Magento. But it's not get triggered when I create shipment for order programatically.

config.xml of custom extension

```
<sales_order_shipment_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <gb_gbgp_CreateParcel>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>gb_gbgp/observer</class>
                        <method>generateParcel</method>
                    </gb_gbgp_CreateParcel>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
```

programatically creating shipment as follows:
public function create(){

```
    $itemQtys = array();
    $orderID = 100000123;
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderID);
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
        if ($orderItem->getQtyToShip() && !$orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            $itemQtys[$orderItem->getId()] = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
        }
    }
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQtys);
    $shipment->register();
    $order->setIsInProcess(true);
    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
             ->addObject($shipment)
             ->addObject($order)
             ->save();

}
The above function creates shipment for order but event doesn't trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

That event will fire when you call `save()` method on the object of class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment`. In your case, that object is $shipment. Try calling `save()` method on $shipment object, and you should be good to go.